# How to store a single column of a single row out of a MySQLi prepared statement in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm very new to PHP and MySQL and I'm looking for a solution to store a single value of a database row in a variable using a prepared statement.

Right now this is the prepared statement and execution:

```
$emailsql = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM User WHERE email = ? limit 1;");
$emailsql->bind_param('s', $email);
$emailsql->execute();
```

I tried `get_result()`, `fetch()`, `fetch_object()` and I'm out of ideas and google search results.

Comment: what happens if you var_dump() whatever comes out of execute()?

Comment: to "store" or "show"? I don't get the question here, or is it just me?

Comment: fetch object  and use `->` to show or assign value to a variable

Comment: I don't know this function yet, is it just `var_dump($emailsql)`?

Comment: Start with the manual then http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and don't deviate from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to your code the binding of the result to a specific variable

```
$emailsql->bind_result($emailResult);
```

And you fetch it :

```
while($emailsql->fetch()){   
  printf ($emailResult); 
}
```

So this should be it:

```
$emailsql = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM User WHERE email = ? limit 1;");
$emailsql->bind_param('s', $email);
$emailsql->execute();
$emailsql->bind_result($emailResult); 
while($emailsql->fetch()){   
  printf ($emailResult); 
}
```

In case you need the variable outside the loop I would take this approach:

```
$theEmail;
$emailsql = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM User WHERE email = ? limit 1;");
$emailsql->bind_param('s', $email);
$emailsql->execute();
$emailsql->bind_result($emailResult); 
while($emailsql->fetch()){   
  $theEmail=$emailResult; 
}
```

Note that you would need an array in order to query more than one email.

Another cleaner approach as @YourCommonSense suggested would be avoiding the loop like so:

```
$theEmail;
$emailsql = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM User WHERE email = ? limit 1;");
$emailsql->bind_param('s', $email);
$emailsql->execute();
$emailsql->bind_result($emailResult); 
$emailsql->fetch();   
printf($emailResult);
```

Comment: You're doing `$emailsql->bind_result($id_comentario);` but printing `$email`; that won't do anything.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I use it quite as a standard because it fits almost any situation.

Comment: What if I want to use this variable outside the loop (and I apparently would)?

Comment: I would declare a variable outside the loop, and then assign the variable of the query to that general variable inside the while. I will edit with an example.

Comment: All this trouble only to follow the "standard"?

Comment: Eh? What do prepared statements to do with your loops? And how this assignment will help at all?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think I missunderstood your comment, what do you mean by standard? btw I agree with your answer, I think PDO is much more cleaner but i don't get the point of the flag approach.

Comment: But I disagree with your answer which is using a loop without a reason and don't let me use the returned variable outside the loop.

Comment: A code sanity is a problem. You are using a loop when multiple results are expected and don't use it otherwise.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Where's the problem of having a loop with just 1 itineration, it doesn't affect performance and you can use it everywhere.Anyway I see your point, it is cleaner. I will add an option with no loop just to contrast them and provide a complete answer, thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: OK, now it looks good. I only corrected one strange statement on the result type.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. Either that bind-result way explained in the other answer, or a conventional method of fetching a regular array

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE email = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row = $res->fetch_row();
$value = $row ? $row[0] : null;
```

Given all that, you may consider the [how bad mysqli's usability is](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison), compared to PDO:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE email = ? limit 1;");
$stmt->execute([$email]);
$value = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```